# Yahoo Finance Adjusted Close for Mutual Funds

Tags: yahoo

I am doing an analysis about Mutual Fund Performance.

I know if I use the Close Prices I can calculate the NAV Returns of a Mutual Funds

But I want to calculate the Total Returns. Can I do it if I use the adjusted close prices of yahoo finance?

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Finance used to include dividends and capital distributions in their calculation of Adjusted Close so you could use Adj Close to calculate total return assuming all distributions are reinvested.  However, it appears that in the past week or two, Yahoo has changed the calcuation and only includes dividend distributions in Adjusted Close which makes them more or less useless.  ETFs, which only have dividend distributions, are still computed properly.